# How to store artifacts at targets using Apache ACE?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, apache-ace

I use Apache Ace to deploy OSGi bundles to so-called targets (see http://ace.apache.org/docs/user-guide.html).

Deployment works fine (deployed bundles will be installed and started), but it looks like deployed bundles are only stored in the OSGi bundle cache. Is there a way to store the bundles as jar files at the target's file system? I use Apache Felix as OSGi runtime and want to store the artifacts at /bundles.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do that, since the ACE management agent manages the install and all updates for you, it makes no sense to store a copy of each bundle as well. It would only take up extra disk space and the framework would not know what to do with those bundles anyway. So I'm curious what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Marcel I think you're right. The problem was, that Felix cleared its cache each time at startup of the framework, so an online connection would be necessary. I solved this issue by setting org.osgi.framework.storage.clean to none. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, that is indeed the way to do it!